# Divide by zero exception on M0+ devices

Tags: arm, embedded, integer-division, cortex-m

Is there a Divide by zero exception on M0+ devices?

I know Cortex M3 and M4 devices have this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cortex-M0+ is ARMv6-M which does not include a divide instruction, so there will be no hardware exception for that.  Since division would necessarily be a software operation, it would be for the software implementation for trap divide-by-zero.  The behaviour will therefore be down to your compiler; for C and C++ at least it is *undefined* behaviour.

Comment: @LPs : On M3, 4 and 7 *integer divide-by-zero* generates a UsageFault exception, Ref.: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/ch02s04s01.html

Comment: @LPs It doesn't have a FPU, but still offers `SDIV` and `UDIV` divide instructions.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, my bad.